# Socket.io: io is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, I am trying to get data on my node.js file instead of directly getting it on my JS file.

I a using Socket.io 2 here, Below is a snapshot of my code and this is also the first time I am using Websocket with Node.

I am doing something like

```
var socket = require('socket.io')

//Home Page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
var cryto = io.connect("https://xyfz.com/);
cryto.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
            console.log(tradeMsg);
          });
res.render("index");
});
```

I also tried something like

```
var io = socket("https://abc.io/");
```

and

```
var socket = require('socket.io')
    var io = socket();
```

which was throwing errors like ***server.listeners*** is not a function and **io.connect** is not a function.

I am certain that I messing up stuff here so can someone guide me about the correct way of doing it?

Comment: If you're trying to make a socket.io connection to some other server, then you need the [`socket.io-client` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client).  The regular `socket.io` server library is for making a socket.io server, not a client.  Also, it is not going to work well for you making a new socket.io connection every single time the `/` request handler is hit.

Comment: **/** should be homepage, I was thinking about a single page website to start with so putting it in a global scope won't make any difference?

Comment: Remember that a server can have many clients.  I doubt you want a new socket.io connection to the crypto service for every single client that ever connects to your server.  You likely want ONE connection from your server that all clients can then benefit from.

Comment: So, your overall code is wrong conceptually.  We could only begin to help you if you back up and explain what you're trying to accomplish.  It does nobody any good to help you fix errors in code that is just wrong to start with.  I can't tell if you should be making a socket.io connection from the web page (not from the server) or if you should be making a connection once from the server upon server initialization and then have the web page connect to the server to get data from that one server-side connection.  Can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am extremely sorry for posting question which might have appeared to be spam. for some reason StackOverflow didn't give me notification for a comment. Secondly, All the questions aren't exactly same. User from stackoverflow cleared my doubt so I can promise you that it won't be posting any similar question again. Again, I am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things which are wrong .

First Consider using Socket.io-client instead of Socket.io.

Second and very much important.

**Never ever make API calls inside your routes. This will trigger a API call everytime user opens your website or webpage**

You can also expect an error "Unexpected headers" or something like that.

Always, Try do declare it outside any routes in your NodeAPP.

Same goes for socket.io as well