# Socket.io-client: NodeJS no response

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Socket.io-client to create a crypto ticker. Here is my code.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var socket = require('socket.io-client');

//Other Important stuff
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/src'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

var io = socket("https://coincap.io/");

io.on('connect', function(){
console.log(io.id); //This displays the ID
});

//Home Page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      console.log("reached here");
io.on('connect', function(tradeMsg){
  console.log(io.connected); //Displays nothing
      var crypto = tradeMsg;
      console.log(crypto); //Displays nothing 
      res.render("index.ejs", {crypto:crypto});
    })
});
```

Now, When I load `localHost:3000` page, it displays ("reached here") but there after it doesn't do anything (besides that load circle on chrome). My console.log also happens to be empty where it should have probably shown something.

here is the sample code for [coincap socket](https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io/blob/master/subscribe.html)

What have I been doing wrong lately?

Comment: Pretty similar code to your prior question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601982/nodejs-variable-scope-reference and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600900/socket-io-io-is-not-defined.  Please stop asking roughly the same question over and over again.  I responded to your first question on this topic and you didn't every say anything after my last comment.  It appears you don't understand the basics of route handlers in a node.js web server which is what I was trying to discuss with you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600900/socket-io-io-is-not-defined

Comment: @jfriend00 didn't know that. Almost the same question 3 times in 5 hours... I do hate it when you try to help and they never answer or at least thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `io.on('connect')` inside `app.get` does absolutely nothing, since you're already connected to coincap. You're missing the `trades` listener which is where you will received the updates.

The example you provided is for client side, so I see two possible alternatives:

**1)** Connect to coincap on the browser, using the example from their github.

```
var socket = io.connect('https://coincap.io');

socket.on('trades', function(tradeMsg) {
    console.log(tradeMsg);
    document.getElementById('trade').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tradeMsg)
});
```

**2)** Get periodic updates from coincap on the server, and serve your home page with the latest data, but this won't be as real time as the first option. And setting a websocket server just to proxy the coincap socket doesn't make any sense.

```
const io = socket("https://coincap.io/");

let crypto;

io.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(io.id); //This displays the ID
});

io.on('trades', function(tradeMsg) {
    // Save latest update
    crypto = tradeMsg;
});

//Home Page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    // Render latest update
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        crypto
    });

});
```

Comment: If I do something like this `io.on('trades', function(tradeMsg){
  console.log(io.connected);
      var crypto = tradeMsg;
      console.log(crypto);
      res.render("index.ejs", {crypto:crypto});
    })
});` it throws TypeError:  `req.next is not a function` . Can you please share the reason for same as well?

Comment: There's a lot wrong in there, no offense :P, Care to join a chat and we go bit by bit, since it will go out of the scope of this question!

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168012/socket-io-client-nodejs-no-response Join here if you want some help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to listen to the 'trades' channel within your socket.io connection, like in the example link - I hope this helps.  Also you need a client to connect on this channel defined.

```
    socket.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
                console.log(tradeMsg);
                io.emit('updated trades', tradeMsg);
            });
```

Comment: When I use **trades** it throws an error     `req.next` is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the client, but you should be listen to an emitted update as 'updated trades'.